# error 1061. T doesn't contain a definition for <propertyName>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, controllers

i am having around 7 models who have same properties(atributes). On view page i am using a model(name = commonModel) which contains all those properties and a extra property to choose in which model's database i want to save that sent data so i created a valuesRelocate Method that will assign all the properties of commonModel to the choosen model (in this case article).
The code i gave below is working but i am getting a error when assigning value of a  property of commonModel to a property of article.
What is  the better way to do this.
Error is at tempModel.question

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
   "Id,question,ans,ruleApplicable,hint,exception,modelSelector")] 
   commonModel commonModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (commonModel.modelSelector == "article")
            {
                article model2 = new article();
                article model1 = valuesRelocate<article>(commonModel, 
   model2);
                db.articleDb.Add(model1);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

            return View(commonModel);
    }

    private T valuesRelocate<T>(commonModel commonModel, T tempModel)   {

        tempModel.question = commonModel.question;
        return tempModel;
    }
```

I am using a abstract base class named baseGrammar .code for both the class is shown below

```
 public abstract class baseGrammar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ans { get; set; }
    public string ruleApplicable { get; set; }
    public string hint { get; set; }
    public bool exception { get; set; }
}
```

the one shown above is base class
and those shown below are derived classes
i use different classes because i wanted to have different classes for different grammatical concepts.

```
public class article : baseGrammar
{

}

 public class commonModel : baseGrammar
{
    [Required]
    public string modelSelector { get; set; }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Do your models have the same base class, or implement an interface? (Aside from anything else, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Can you tell which line of code is showing error? Can you share the code of `valuesRelocate` method too?

Comment: I have provided code of valuesRelocate method and question in tempModel.question inside the valuesRelocate method is showing error. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You're still not using .NET names - `article` would be `Article` etc. I *strongly, strongly* advise you to follow the naming convention of the platform you're working in.

Comment: The method does not know that T is of type `baseGrammer` or `article` so it doesn't know about its properties. That's why you are seeing this error. What you need to do is use generic constraint. `private T valuesRelocate<T>(commonModel commonModel, T tempModel) where T : baseGrammer` that's how you need to declare the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to *constrain* the type parameter `T` to be derived from your base class:

```
// Names changed to follow .NET naming conventions
private T RelocateValues<T>(BaseGrammar baseModel, T tempModel)
    where T : BaseGrammar
{
    tempModel.question = baseModel.question;
    return tempModel;
}
```

However, given that you're modifying the incoming model, you could remove the return value and just change the method to:

```
private void RelocateValues(BaseGrammar from, BaseGrammar to)
{
    to.question = from.question;
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
Article model = new Article();
RelocateValues(model);
db.ArticleDb.Add(model);
```

There's no need to have two separate variables which will refer to the same object anyway...

Comment: @himanshu: Sorry, I meant it to be `BaseGrammar`, not `CommonModel`. The point is that the property is declared in the base class. Edited.

Comment: Sorry but this wont work because my main aim is to convert the CommonModel to other models which in this case is Article but it could be any like Noun or Pronoun in the production Enviroment.
But you are here making changes from CommonModel to CommonModel. 
What needs to be done is Article.Property = CommonModel.Property

However it is now working when i  specified where T : BaseGrammar but i feel my app is working slower now  @JonSkeet

Comment: @himanshu: Please see my previous reply to your now-deleted comment. As for your app "working slower" - it wasn't working *at all* before, because it didn't compile. The code I've provided will have no significant performance impact at all...